# openshift origin v0.3.3 error starting docker registry pod on centos 6.6

Tags: docker, centos6, openshift-origin

I'm running https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/v0.3.3 on centos 6.6. When i run:

```
sudo /opt/bin/openshift start
```

i see an error:

```
I0301 22:02:04.738381   18093 pod_cache.go:194] error getting pod deploy-docker-registry-16mttp status: Get http://localhost:10250/api/v1beta1/podInfo?podID=deploy-docker-registry-16mttp&podNamespace=default: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10250: connection refused, retry later
E0301 22:02:04.738422   18093 pod_cache.go:260] Error getting info for pod default/deploy-docker-registry-16mttp: Get http://localhost:10250/api/v1beta1/podInfo?podID=deploy-docker-registry-16mttp&podNamespace=default: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10250: connection refused
```

If i do:

```
docker ps -a | grep origin-deployer
```

then i see:

```
b207ce593385        openshift/origin-deployer:v0.3.3   "/usr/bin/openshift-   31 hours ago        Exited (255) 31 hours ago                       k8s_deployment.6c8f5c13_deploy-docker-registry-16mttp.default.api_11ae6e53-bf85-11e4-b8b2-080027bb06ce_8c701fc0
```

so i run:

```
docker logs b207ce593385
```

and get:

```
228 20:06:37.955877       1 deployer.go:64] Get https://10.0.2.15:8443/api/v1beta1/replicationControllers/docker-registry-1?namespace=default: dial tcp 10.0.2.15:8443: no route to host
```

If i do:

```
ping 10.0.2.15
```

it works. If i try:

```
https://10.0.2.15:8443
```

it returns:

```
404 Page Not Found
```

so the server is responsive. If i open the OpenShift Web Console at https://10.0.2.15:8444/ and Browse the default project it shows one deploy-docker-registry-16mttp pod with a status of Failed. The "IP on node" is 172.17.0.3 and it does respond to a ping. If i run:

```
osc describe service docker-registry
```

it returns:

```
Name:       docker-registry
Labels:     docker-registry=default
Selector:   docker-registry=default
Port:       5000
Endpoints:  <empty>
No events.
```

it should be returning:

```
Endpoints:  172.17.0.60:5000
```

according to the instructions. When i try:

```
ping 172.17.0.60
```

it returns:

```
PING 172.17.0.60 (172.17.0.60) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.17.42.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.17.42.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
     ...
```

Lot of moving parts and i'm new to it so any suggestions would be appreciated. I've probably missed one of the configuration steps.

Comment: if i run a centos:centos7 container then i can ping 10.0.2.15 from a bourne shell running inside it

Comment: According to IRC most of the devs are now working with Fedora 20+ or Centos 7 so i'll give them another try. My initial attempt to install Centos 7 failed on VirtualBox on the mac because it drops bluetooth support during the install.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to Centos 6.6. When i try the same process on Centos 7 (using netinstall) there is no problem.